# Sample Gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I’m doing a programming assignment on sample gamma distributions in R. I used a loop to create histograms of a total of 49 different samples, each with different parameters. I was then asked to compare the theoretical mean and variance to the sample mean and variance for each of the 49 cases. I used a loop to create vectors of each of the sample means etc. However, I am getting answers such as (1.0e+00) where in this case, the answer should just be one. How do I solve this problem? I hope Ive given enough information and am making sense, if not I can clarify further, I have never done any probability programming so I’m relatively new to it.

Comment: Is this a formatting issue?  `1.0e+00` means $1 \times 10^0$ and that is $1$

Answer (score 2):

Your programming efforts are probably correct, but you might not be familiar with [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). It's quite widely used in programming contexts and one of the default output formats of R.

The part after the `e` is the exponent of 10, so $10^{0}$, and you need to multiply that by the part before the `e`. This yields $1 \times 1.0 = 1$, as you expected.

As described [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318351/4751173) (and in the other answer), you can disable it with `options(scipen = 999)` and it's possible to put that in your .Rprofile file so it becomes the default for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a formatting issue, just run the following command which will suppress the scientific notation:

```r
options(scipen = 9999)
```